# Arduino, MAX232, how to control RTS

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to send some data to a device which is connected to my arduino using a db-9 connector. I created the following setup:
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoSoftwareRS232

It seems that the other device is expecting RTS to go from -5V to +5V and have RTS +5V while sending. Is it possible to adjust my setup to control RTS this way? Do I need some addition components on my board to do this?

```
default: RTS = -5V
start sending data: RTS = +5V
sending data: RTS = +5V
finished sending data: RTS = -5V
```

I tried to connect RTS and CTS but that did not do the trick because I have to change RTS  on my side first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you wire the connector as shown?  Did it work using the terminal program?

Comment: No, that's completely the wrong chip to get the job done, it doesn't support the handshake signals.  They probably picked it because Arduino firmware doesn't support them either.  Ask at electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you connected pin 6 to pin 4? These pins indicate that the other therminal is conected (Data Terminal Ready). If you are going to comunicate at low speed (say 9600 or bellow), I think you do not need handshaking (do not use RTS and CTS, DTR and DSR, just connect they to each other at the device side)